# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS not resolving us.archive.ubuntu.com

Tags: networking, apt, updates

After recently installing ubuntu 18.04.2 onto my laptop and running 'sudo apt-get update', I get a bunch of issues that pop up. They mainly tell me, "Could not resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'" or "Could not resolve 'security.ubuntu.com'".

I do want to add that my laptop does not seem to be connected to the WiFi so it might not be detecting my networks card.

## Full Output

```
Err:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
  Could not resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
  Could not resolve 'security.ubuntu.com'
Err:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
  Could not resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
  Could not resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease  Could not resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/InRelease  Could not resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-backports/InRelease  Could not resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-security/InRelease  Could not resolve 'security.ubuntu.com'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: The ppa is fine, the problem is you are not connected to the internet.

Answer (score 0):

Immediately after the BIOS/UEFI splash screen during boot, with BIOS, quickly press and hold the Shift key, which will bring up the GNU GRUB menu. (If you see the Ubuntu logo, you've missed the point where you can enter the GRUB menu.) With UEFI press (perhaps several times) the Esc key to get to the GRUB menu. Sometimes the manufacturer's splash screen is a part of the Windows bootloader, so when you power up the machine it goes straight to the GRUB screen, and then pressing Shift is unnecessary.

The timing when to press the left Shift key can be tricky, so sometimes if you miss it you need to try it again. If that doesn't work try the answers to I can't get the GRUB menu to show up during boot.

From the GRUB screen select Advanced options for Ubuntu and press Enter.

A new purple screen will appear showing a list of kernels, which includes options of booting the kernels normally or in recovery mode.

Once you're in recovery mode, click networking. Once you did that, click dpkg. After all that click resume.

This works for me.